# Wordpress/Gutenberg Sidebar squeezed to the right

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using gutenberg with wordpress and the sidebar where I can edit the blocks is squeezed to the right, making it impossible for me to edit it:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the sidebar is shown partially on the screen and I can´t move to the right.

Here are some things I tried:

1 - Work with another browser (Chrome and Edge). It did not work.
2 - Edditing the code in the plugin (Twenty Twenty), stylesheet in Gutenberg and Stackable plugin:

```
'mode' => 'edit'
//------------------------------------------------
// Admin CSS
//------------------------------------------------

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo 
  '<style>
    .wp-block {max-width: 900px;}
  </style>';
}
```

As explained in: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-blocks-cramped-in-right-sidebar-of-editor/

Nothing of these worked. Does anyone have a clue?

Tks

Comment: Yea, i've had the same issue too!!! Not sure it's a bug in the ```gutenberg block editor``` or its related to other plugins! On the upper right corner you see three little dots, click on them, and then click on the "Full screen mode" to exit out of the "full screen window", it might help solve the issue. There is also a shortcut for getting out of the "full screen mode"! On windows it's "Ctrl + Shift + Alt + F".

Answer (score 4):

Try to overwrite the css box with this code:

```
.interface-complementary-area {
    width: 380px !important;
}
```

Or in your theme functions.php add this:

```
// Wider sidebar on gutenberg backend
function my_wider_sidebar() {
    echo 
    '<style>
        .interface-complementary-area{ width: 450px !important; }
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_wider_sidebar');
```